# Setting Up Virtual hosts for XAMPP on windows

Tags: windows-xp, xampp, virtualhost

XAMPP for Windows 1.8.2 PHP 5.4, 
Operating System : windows xp

I am using username and passowrd on XAMPP

c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
127.0.0.1 hindustans.local
127.0.0.1 read.local

E:\My Projects\wesites\read
index.html

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
    <Directory "E:/My Projects/wesites/read">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
  </VirtualHost>
   <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:/My Projects/wesites/read"
    ServerName read
    Options +Indexes
    </VirtualHost>
```

read.local works fine with c:\xampp\htdocs
But 
read.local doesn't work with E:\My Projects\wesites\read\index.html

I  brief want to run my project from  E:\My Projects\wesites\read

Comment: Can you access your folder? Do you have permission to do that? Do you have an index file? Also, why do you want to host the website on Windows XP???

Comment: Refer this its work for me --
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2658510/13248471

Answer (score 0):

You need match the ServerName to the address you have in hosts and give it permission

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:/My Projects/wesites/read"
    ServerName read.local
    <Directory "E:/My Projects/wesites/read" >
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>`

then try to access the site at read.local.

More info [here](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=190038&sid=a8eac7e615c828c5cdd6fcf420c4c519)