# How to access a site on Codero without a domain name and without appending the username to the end

Tags: php, .htaccess, whm

Yesterday i have created a new site on my Codero Dedicated Server. and i have not assigned any domain name yet to the ip address.

Currently i am able to access my site with http://MySiteIpAddress/~username but i want to access it with only http://MySiteIpAddress/. Is there any way to do it. I don't know if that's  possible by htaccess rules, so any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You want to setup a virtual host and point it to the folder you want.

[See this other post for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658173/setup-apache-virtualhost-windows)

> You need to do several steps in order to make this work.
>
> **1.) Update the `hosts` file.** On Windows XP, you can find it under `c:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\`. You should already see the first
>   line from below, it takes care of your mentioned other project. - add
>   the additional ones to make any requests to the mentioned virtual
>   hosts routed back to your own machine.
>
> ```
> 127.0.0.1       localhost
> 127.0.0.1       foo-bar.com
> 127.0.0.1       abcdef.com
> 127.0.0.1       qwerty.com
> ```
>
> **2.) Update the vhosts file in Apache configuration.** Under your XAMPP folder, add the following to
>   `apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` and if needed change the ports
>   (i.e. if you use 8080 instead of port 80).
>
> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>   DocumentRoot C:/xampplite/htdocs/foo-bar/
>   ServerName www.foo-bar.com
> </VirtualHost>
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>   DocumentRoot C:/xampplite/htdocs/abcdef/
>   ServerName www.abcdef.com
> </VirtualHost>
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>   DocumentRoot C:/xampplite/htdocs/qwerty/web/
>   ServerName www.qwerty.com
> </VirtualHost>
> ```
>
> **3.) Do a quick configuration check.** Open `{XAMPP-folder}\apache\conf\httpd.conf` your file and make sure that
>   the following part is not commented out by a preceeding `#` character:
>
> ```
> Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
> ```
>
> **4.) Restart XAMPP.**
>
> ... and you should be all setup now. Your other project should
>   be accessible at the URI you mentioned if you just put it under
>   `C:/xampplite/htdocs/my-project/`.

Comment: thanks for answer but, i want to access my site with ip address only and without username , 
currenty http://Mysiteipaddress/~username is working
but http://Mysiteipaddress/ is not working