# how to add virtual host?

Tags: php, host

for windows open this path

```
c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

open in notpad or texteditor
show hidden files Must be on to open this path

host file view some thing like this

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Add your host ip and host name

```
192.168.10.88       myhost
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below url which might help you out for creating virtual host on window

[ReferenceLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658173/setup-apache-virtualhost-windows)