# Moving website to localhost: Document Root changed

Tags: php, html

I have download a website that was written from scratch using PHP, MySql, html, css, jQuery.

After fixing some configuration with MySql and htaccess, I get to a point where all my CSS and JS files are not loaded because of a relative path error.

This is how it looks:
[image]

The error in the console `GET http://localhost/fonts/fonts.css` sends me to `index.php` which loads all those files with a relative path.
Now, if I remove the `/` at the beginning of each line, the files will be loaded, however, I get more errors on different pages with bad URLs and such, that means that I need to fix this `/` problem instead of just renaming the hrefs.

So my question is, how to fix it?

I have tried to set a base href tag:
`<base href="http://localhost/israelrescue/">`
or
`<base href="http://localhost/israelrescue">`
or in PHP:
`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = 'http://localhost/israelrescue';`
or
`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/israelrescue/';`

P.S:

> <kbd>israelrescue</kbd> is the name of the folder I am using in my localhost installation for this website.

Nothing seems to work, any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: send your live url

Comment: @MukeshPanchal what do you mean? it's installed on my laptop, locally, there is no live link. The website link is https://israelrescue.org/ if that helps...

Comment: It's because you've got the site in a subfolder in `localhost`. Is it possible for you to move the site into the root? I think @MukeshPanchal is telling you to load the assets from live, which is missing the point somewhat.

Comment: Looks like this site was not written to be run from within a sub-folder. Easiest way to work around that would be to set up a VirtualHost for this project in your local server, so that you can load it directly via a local domain name, without any additional path. (And btw., setting DOCUMENT_ROOT to an HTTP URL is complete nonsense.)

Comment: It is possible, however, this site has tons of files and folders. I would like to avoid having a mess in my `www` folder because I am working on other sites at the same time.

Comment: @CBroe `setting DOCUMENT_ROOT to an HTTP URL is complete nonsense.` - I figured but wanted to try anyway.
Could you explain how to get the VirtualHost solution working please? if that would be a solution you could write it as a solution post and I will accept if it works. :)

Comment: How to configure VirtualHosts is something you can research. Specifics depend on what web server you are using.

Comment: please follow the link and make a virtual host in your computer if you use a windows machine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658173/setup-apache-virtualhost-windows

Comment: I understand, thank you for your replies!

Answer (score 0):

Answers:

> It's because you've got the site in a subfolder in localhost. Is it possible for you to move the site into the root? I think @MukeshPanchal is telling you to load the assets from live, which is missing the point somewhat. – thebluefox
>
> Looks like this site was not written to be run from within a
>   sub-folder. Easiest way to work around that would be to set up a
>   VirtualHost for this project in your local server, so that you can
>   load it directly via a local domain name, without any additional path.
>   (And btw., setting DOCUMENT_ROOT to an HTTP URL is complete nonsense.)
>   – CBroe

Answer (score 0):

You can leave the site in its subfolder as long as you drop the "/" in the beggining of every file path :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/common.js"></script>
```

becomes

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/common.js"></script>
```

Should work like this

Comment: True, I already mentioned this in my original post. However, it wouldn't help me with the rest of the website because I only changed something locally in one file and one line. I needed a more general solution and VirtualHosts recommended by @CBroe worked well.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't see that. Yes ! You can configure a virtualhost pointing directly to that folder under the ServerName "ir.localhost" and add a host entry "127.0.0.1 ir.localhost" in your `/etc/hosts` that way, your site would be at root level of that host.